# Can Hibernate automatically map a HashMap to a string column?

Tags: json, hibernate

I have a HashMap which was populated from form elements of an HTML page, and when I save it I need Hibernate to convert it automatically to a JSON string and also persist it as a JSON string. Is this doable in Hibernate? Or, can you tell Hibernate in the mapping file (or maybe, as an annotation) to call a Java method that converts HashMap to JSON, and persist the return value of that method, and vice-versa? (read JSON string and convert automatically to a HashMap).

Thanks for all the help!

Answer (score 0):

Sure, you can just create a custom user type:

http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.6/reference/en-US/html/types.html#types-custom

Hibernate will then use this to persist data to the database, and to read it back as object.